# How are allocator in C++ implemented?

Tags: c++, memory-management

I was trying to understand a bit better `std::allocator` in C++, I came across [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/238037/why-stdallocators-are-not-that-popular), and it seems to me there's actually only one allocator class typically used by containers (like `std::vector`) my question is how is such allocator implemented? Is it like a stack which is periodically re-allocated? If not how is it actually implemented?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The default allocator is [`std::allocator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator), and just uses `::operator new` as and when required, so nothing special. It's more or less the same as doing `new` and `delete` yourself for each object needed. You can read more about it under `[default.allocator]` in the standard.

The allocator "interface" (really just a set of requirements, enforced during template instantiation) is a wrapper around this process, allowing alternative memory provisioning approaches to be employed.

For example, alternative allocators that you may provide could implement a [memory pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_pool) or something else that's specific to your needs, cutting down on honest-to-goodness dynamic allocations.

Standard containers have, as well as their element type, an allocator type as template argument (you usually don't notice this!) and this is how you select alternative implementations for use with that container.

In these cases you'll generally be pre-allocating some big chunk of memory then dishing out little chunks as and when. In that sense, such an implementation could be considered a sort of "heap within a heap", but really there's no reason you need to give it heap semantics at all. It only needs to abide by the requirements of the concept [*Allocator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator).

Mr Josuttis has put a (boring) example up at http://www.josuttis.com/cppcode/allocator.html; I reproduce it here:

```
/* The following code example is taken from the book
 * "The C++ Standard Library - A Tutorial and Reference"
 * by Nicolai M. Josuttis, Addison-Wesley, 1999
 *
 * (C) Copyright Nicolai M. Josuttis 1999.
 * Permission to copy, use, modify, sell and distribute this software
 * is granted provided this copyright notice appears in all copies.
 * This software is provided "as is" without express or implied
 * warranty, and with no claim as to its suitability for any purpose.
 */
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>

namespace MyLib {
   template <class T>
   class MyAlloc {
     public:
       // type definitions
       typedef T        value_type;
       typedef T*       pointer;
       typedef const T* const_pointer;
       typedef T&       reference;
       typedef const T& const_reference;
       typedef std::size_t    size_type;
       typedef std::ptrdiff_t difference_type;

       // rebind allocator to type U
       template <class U>
       struct rebind {
           typedef MyAlloc<U> other;
       };

       // return address of values
       pointer address (reference value) const {
           return &value;
       }
       const_pointer address (const_reference value) const {
           return &value;
       }

       /* constructors and destructor
        * - nothing to do because the allocator has no state
        */
       MyAlloc() throw() {
       }
       MyAlloc(const MyAlloc&) throw() {
       }
       template <class U>
         MyAlloc (const MyAlloc<U>&) throw() {
       }
       ~MyAlloc() throw() {
       }

       // return maximum number of elements that can be allocated
       size_type max_size () const throw() {
           return std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max() / sizeof(T);
       }

       // allocate but don't initialize num elements of type T
       pointer allocate (size_type num, const void* = 0) {
           // print message and allocate memory with global new
           std::cerr << "allocate " << num << " element(s)"
                     << " of size " << sizeof(T) << std::endl;
           pointer ret = (pointer)(::operator new(num*sizeof(T)));
           std::cerr << " allocated at: " << (void*)ret << std::endl;
           return ret;
       }

       // initialize elements of allocated storage p with value value
       void construct (pointer p, const T& value) {
           // initialize memory with placement new
           new((void*)p)T(value);
       }

       // destroy elements of initialized storage p
       void destroy (pointer p) {
           // destroy objects by calling their destructor
           p->~T();
       }

       // deallocate storage p of deleted elements
       void deallocate (pointer p, size_type num) {
           // print message and deallocate memory with global delete
           std::cerr << "deallocate " << num << " element(s)"
                     << " of size " << sizeof(T)
                     << " at: " << (void*)p << std::endl;
           ::operator delete((void*)p);
       }
   };

   // return that all specializations of this allocator are interchangeable
   template <class T1, class T2>
   bool operator== (const MyAlloc<T1>&,
                    const MyAlloc<T2>&) throw() {
       return true;
   }
   template <class T1, class T2>
   bool operator!= (const MyAlloc<T1>&,
                    const MyAlloc<T2>&) throw() {
       return false;
   }
}
```

And usage:

```
#include <vector>
#include "myalloc.hpp"

int main()
{
    // create a vector, using MyAlloc<> as allocator
    std::vector<int,MyLib::MyAlloc<int> > v;

    // insert elements
    // - causes reallocations
    v.push_back(42);
    v.push_back(56);
    v.push_back(11);
    v.push_back(22);
    v.push_back(33);
    v.push_back(44);
}
```

Comment: But how do a container and an allocator interacts? Say I have a list of integers and I want to insert a new integer value, naively I would use `new` to allocate a new node and link it appropriately. What would an allocator do differently?

Comment: The default allocator does nothing differently. Your own alternative could return a pointer to some position in a pre-allocated store instead, or a pointer to some memory stored on a pigeon's wings

Comment: Are there actual examples where no default allocator are actually used?

Comment: If you want to see literally how it's implemented then take a peek into your stdlib's source code, but honestly it won't be very interesting. The allocator has "functions" that abide by "give me some memory" and "take some memory back" and that's it

Comment: Sure, plenty. Google for `C++ memory pool allocator` or some such thing.

Comment: Just to clarify, all containers in the standard library just use the default allocator. Nothing special, is it correct? just a wrapper around the `new/delete` operators.

Comment: Standard containers _by default_ use the default allocator (which, indeed, is just a wrapper around `new` & `delete`). But it's a template argument so you can make them use whatever you want. I've added a further link.

Comment: Do note that the Josuttis example is from 1999 and, among other things, I'd expect (though I haven't checked) functions like `construct` to be "better" nowadays to make use of move semantics.

Comment: @Nik-Lz Like most useful C++ meta-utilities, it's dry and esoteric. That's not Nicolai's fault though... at least not completely ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Allocators just provide a policy for allocating memory, deallocating memory, constructing object and destroying them.

They do not provide a policy to reallocate memory (increasing the size of a previously allocated memory region). So in all containers, if the memory must be increased:

- either the container allocate a new memory chunk,
- or as `vector` does, allocate a new larger memory region, copy the old elements inside it and then release the previous memory region.

Comment: This answer seems to be more about how containers request memory, rather than how the allocator provides it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit So I am answering the question and you don't??

Comment: Quite the opposite in my opinion but perhaps that's just me!