# difference between `explicit vector( size_type count, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );` and `std::vector<T,Allocator>::reserve`

Tags: c++, vector, stl

What's the difference between

```cpp
std::vector<uint8_t> vec1(size);
```

and

```cpp
std::vector<uint8_t> vec2;
vec2.reserve(size);
```

Do they both allocate memory on heap?

Comment: There's no difference between constructor and `resize()`, but your title asks about `reserve()`, not `resize()`?

Comment: sorry, it's a typo. I'm asking ```reserve()```

Answer (score 1):

Both pieces of code allocate memory. The difference is:

- `vec1.size()` equals `size`
- `vec2.size()` equals 0

That is, `vec1` not only has memory allocated, but also the elements itself are initialized and can be accessed.

`vec2`, however, is still empty, and you must filled it with values using `resize`, `push_back`, etc. As long as you do not insert more than `vec2.capacity()` (which is at least `size`) elements, no reallocation happens.

Answer (score 0):

> What's the difference?

The difference is that the first method sets the capacity of `vec1` in the constructor, which means it can be filled with `size` elements of type `uint8_t` without reallocation. Yet `vec2` needs to reallocate memory if `size` is greater than `vec2.capacity()`, which means that it needs to call the member function `allocate()` of `std::allocator<uint8_t>` for twice. For further information, please check the [document](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve).

> Do they both allocate memory on the heap?

Generally speaking, `allocate()` does allocate memory from something called [memory pool](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.1?topic=concepts-memory-pools#:%7E:text=A%20memory%20pool%20is%20a,and%20programs%20into%20memory%20pools.) in heap. Yet it is not the only choice. We can call any implementation that conforms to the [requirement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator) an allocator, yet we don't specify how it works. A similar and fully implemented answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52255423/16941344).

Here I'd like to provide a trivial and incomplete example to show container does not have to allocate memory from heap:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class my_allocator {
 private:
  // max size for allocation
  static constexpr size_type MAX_SIZE = 64;
  // data
  int8_t _data[MAX_SIZE];
};
```

In this case, as long as we implement all interfaces required by the standard, we can allocate memory from an array in the stack.

Comment: Your fixed-size allocator would create problems if used in allocator-aware containers. Indeed, containers store an instance of the allocator, which should be a handle to a memory resource. Since your allocator performs allocate and deallocate operations on the stored array, it means that the handle is conjuncted with the memory resource. Thus, each container stores directly the resources. It would not be possible to perform a move construct, move assign or swap operation safely:

Comment: while pointers to the resources would be moved or swapped, allocators, and in this case the corresponding memory resources, would be copied or swapped, performing the copy of the containers resources. As a result, each container would point to the resources that are stored in the allocator of the other container.

Comment: @Quuplaxone might provide a more detailed explanation than me ;)